# The 'await' operator can only be used with an async lambda expression

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5

I'm trying to copy a list of files to a directory. I'm using async / await. 
But I've been getting this compilation error

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda
>   expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async'
>   modifier.

This is what my code looks like

```
async Task<int> CopyFilesToFolder(List<string> fileList, 
            IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken ct)
{
    int totalCount = fileList.Count;
    int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
    {
        int tempCount = 0;
        foreach (var file in fileList)
        {
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(outputPath, file);

            await CopyFileAsync(file, outputFile); //<-- ERROR: Compilation Error 

            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            tempCount++;
            if (progress != null)
            {
                progress.Report((tempCount * 100 / totalCount)));
            }

        }

        return tempCount;
    });
    return processCount;
}


private async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
{
    using (Stream source = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (Stream destination = File.Create(destinationPath))
        {
            await source.CopyToAsync(destination);
        }
    }

}
```

Pls can anyone point out what am I missing here ?

Comment: You haven't marked the lambda with the `async` keyword? Basically, if you extracted the lambda inside `Task.Run` it would not be an `async` method, so you couldn't await the result.

Comment: `await Task.Run<int>(() => ...` -- the lambda is not `async`.

Comment: This should be written without a lambda or `Task.Run`, because it's only IO-bound work. See http://pastebin.com/p83gkkTk for an example solution (I'd post this as an answer, but it's already closed).

Comment: @TimS.Thanks for that, Yes I Agree.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
```

Should be

```
int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(async () =>
```

Remember that a *lambda* is just shorthand for defining a *method*. So, your outer method is `async`, but in this case you're trying to use `await` within a lambda (which is a *different* method than your outer method). So your lambda must be marked `async` as well.

Comment: Something about `await Task.Run<int>(async () =>` seems redundant to me. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: @TimS.: No; each part is important and means something different. `async () =>` makes the *lambda* `async`, `Task.Run` runs that lambda on a thread pool thread, and `await` means that the calling method is (asynchronously) waiting for that lambda to complete.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: `Task.Run` seems to usually be used to offload something that would, otherwise, be synchronous, CPU-bound work. This doesn't appear to have any significant CPU work, just IO-bound work. So wouldn't it be possible, and better, to write it in a way that doesn't use `Task.Run`, but simply `await`s an asynchronous method?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, using `Task.Run` for I/O work is superfluous, and that does appear to be the case here.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks!
`Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidOperationException>(async () => await this.eligibilityService.GetEligibility(eligibilityCriteriaModel)).Result;`

Comment: @ToddVance: I'd recommend using `await` instead of `Result`.